# Windows 10 Acer - Hard drive powers down and up constantly when screen goes off and on battery

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, acer-aspire

Strange one this.  I can't tell if this is a Windows 10 or an Acer issue.

Model number: A315-41-R9YH

When on battery and the screen turns off, I can hear the hard drive constantly powering down and up.  It sounds like it's going through hell.  This doesn't happen when connected to the mains.

Check out video in the link.  You might have to turn the volume up.  You can hear the hard drive doing the thing I mention once the screen goes off.

I thought it might be the power settings.  So I went to advanced power settings and set "Turn off hard disk after 0 minutes (i.e. never)" on both battery and power but it didn't make a difference.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVO7Bkz1t64

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  I'll update my question.  It's a new laptop so hopefully not a failing HDD or battery.  Good idea on the Linux distro.  I'll try this and update my answer with this as well.

Comment: So I had other issues getting Ubuntu to boot from USB.  Some other non-related Ubuntu hardware compatibility issue.  Googling, it seems like a known Ubuntu problem that I don't have time to resolve now.  But I did get a response on the Acer community forums that solves the problem so I'll post it here as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted on the Acer community forums and got a response there that solved the issue for me.  Quoted as-is below.  N.B. Problem still slightly noticeable sometimes when laptop goes to sleep on battery.

> OK. Open Control Panel. Search power plan. Select change what the power buttons do in the left panel. Click change settins that are unavailable. Scroll down the list and uncheck fast startup to disable fast boot. Reboot machine. If that solves the problem, leave it in cold slow boot mode cuz it solves a lot of other problems that crop up from time to time. Jack E/NJ

Workaround I used before trying the above:
In the meantime, I just disabled the screen going black (Power Options -> Change plan settings -> Turn off display -> Never) to avoid the issue from happening.